# Display a variable from popup in another page in a new tab

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a popup page containing an array,
let's say

```
arr[key1] = foo;
arr[key2] = bar;
arr[key3] = foobar;
```

The array keys are displayed in the popup page in different buttons.

When the user click on a key, I want its value to open in a new page in a  new tab.

for example,
when clicking button "KEY3", a new tab will open and display "FOOBAR".

How can I do this?

*Thanks*

Answer (score 0):

Well, you just need dictionary ...

```
 var arr = {}; 
 arr['key1'] = 'foo';
 arr['key2'] = 'bar'; 
 arr['key3'] = 'foobar';
```

If you want to persist those, then you can use localStorage directly.

```
 localStorage['key1'] = 'foo';
 localStorage['key2'] = 'bar'; 
 localStorage['key3'] = 'foobar';
```

To Open a new page, you can you use http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-create

Comment: Thanks, but actually I know all those things. My problem is that I need an action in the popup page (clicking a button) will take affect in the other page. how can I pass the variable from the popup to the other page?

Comment: If you use localStorage, that data is persisted for your extension. You can just retrieve it back ... Or you could store the value in the background page and read it again from your other extension page. http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#method-getBackgroundPage